# Undefined object being passed via Requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using `Requirejs` to load the JavaScript in our web app. The issues is that I'm getting an `undefined` object being passed to a module which, when used in other modules, is instantiated perfectly fine.

OK, here's the setup. My `main.js` file which requirejs runs on startup:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/scripts",
    paths: {
        demographics: "Demographics/demographics",
        complaints: "Complaints/complaints",
    }
});

require(["templates", "demographics", "complaints", "crossDomain"], function (templates, demographics, complaints) {
    "use strict";

    console.log("0");
    console.log(demographics === undefined);

    demographics.View.display();
});
```

A lot of the config has been stripped to just the core files in this problem.

Here's `Demographics.js`:

```
define(["ko", "templates", "complaints", "globals", "underscore"], function (ko, templates, complaints, globals) {

    // Stuff removed.
    return {
        View: view
    };
});
```

and `Complaints.js`

```
define([
    "demographics",
    "ko",
    "templates",
    "complaints",
    "visualeffects",
    "globals",
    "webservice",
    "underscore",
    "typewatcher",
    "imagesloaded"],
    function (demographics, ko, templates, complaints, visualeffects, globals, webservice) {
        "use strict";


        console.log("1");
        console.log(demographics === undefined);
    return {
        View: view
    };
});
```

The problem is this - in `Complaints.js` the `demographics` parameter passed via the `define` config is `undefined`. The console log out tells me that "demographics === undefined" is `true`.

However, when the main.js file executes, the demographics parameter passed to it is not undefined, it is, as expected, an instantiated object.

Now I'm stuck since I can't see why in `complaints.js` that demographics variable is undefined. Can anyone spot what I'm missing please?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You have a circular dependency.  The `demographics` module depends on `complaints` and `complaints` depends on `demographics`.  As per the [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular):

> If you define a circular dependency (a needs b and b needs a), then in this case when b's module function is called, it will get an undefined value for a.

The solution, if you can't remove the circular dependency, is to asynchronously require one of the two modules within the other on demand (say when the view is instantiated instead of when the module that defines the view is executed).  Again, the [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular) cover this topic fairly well.

Comment: Ahh, exactly what I suspected, but really didn't think this could happen (I'm a real newbie with this AMD/requirejs stuff :) My plan of action is to create another module which will host the code for both the demographics and the complains. That means this new module will be used to call the code from the other two files. Thanks for confirming my thoughts. Will give it a try when I get the time.

Answer (score 28):

Another case is when you accidentally type `require` instead of `define` when defining a module, took me some time to notice this.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem. In my case, when defining a module, I'd written:

```
define('some_dependency', ...
```

instead of

```
define(['some_dependency'], ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Another possible reason is implementing the module's interface (AMD, CommonJS), but forgetting to return anything. I just did that.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered another reason:

```
define(function () {
    return {};
}()); // <-- notice the '()' typo.
```

This "typo" causes no JS errors for this one and can make it confusing to figure out especially in a complicated application with many potential circular dependancies.

The reason, of course, is the "typo" is valid JS that simply calls the function you define thereby passing its result to `define()` rather then the function as intended.

Answer (score 0):

One other possible reason that may look obvious in hindsight is an error in your module's code. In my case, I was trying to get an attribute from an undefined variable. The error is logged in the console, but for some reason I was not seeing it/mistaking it for the undefined module error.